# Is there any faster way in python to split strings to sublists in a list with 1million elements？

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

I'm trying to help my friend to clean an order list dataframe with one million elements.

[image]

you can see that the product_name column should be a list, but they are in string type. So I want to split them into sublists.

Here's my code：

```
order_ls = raw_df['product_name'].tolist()
cln_order_ls = list()
for i in order_ls:
    i = i.replace('[', '')
    i = i.replace(']', '')
    i = i.replace('\'', '')
    cln_order_ls.append(i)

new_cln_order_ls = list()
for i in cln_order_ls:
    new_cln_order_ls.append(i.split(', '))
```

But in the 'split' part, it took lots of time to process. I'm wondering is there faster way to deal with it ？

Thanks~

Comment: What about `ast.literal_eval()`? e.g. `import ast; ast.literal_eval("['ciao', 'pippo']")` which gives you: `['ciao', 'pippo']`

Comment: @norok2 I've tried this func, but it still took a lot of time doing so. But thanks :)

Comment: Check my answer for a more comprehensive battery of tests. But basically you cannot beat `.split()` speed (it approaches C speed). However, you could optimize some other parts and avoid direct looping which will buy you some speed for very large datasets (~500k rows or more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

**(I did not like last answer, it was too much confused, so I reordered it and tested I little bit more systematically).**

## Long story short:

For speed, just use:

```
def str_to_list(s):
    return s[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(', ')


df['product_name'].apply(str_to_list).to_list()
```

---

## Long story long:

Let's dissect your code:

```py
order_ls = raw_df['product_name'].tolist()
cln_order_ls = list()
for i in order_ls:
    i = i.replace('[', '')
    i = i.replace(']', '')
    i = i.replace('\'', '')
    cln_order_ls.append(i)

new_cln_order_ls = list()
for i in cln_order_ls:
    new_cln_order_ls.append(i.split(', '))
```

What you would really like to do is to have a function, say `str_to_list()` which converts your input `str`ing to a `list`.

For some reasons, you do it in multiple steps, but this is really not necessary. What you have so far, can be rewritten as:

```
def str_to_list_OP(s):
    return s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '').split(', ')
```

If you can assume that `[` and `]` are always the first and last char of your string, you can simplify this to:

```
def str_to_list(s):
    return s[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(', ')
```

which should also be faster.

Alternative approaches would use regular expressions, e.g.:

```
def str_to_list_regex(s):
    regex = re.compile(r'[\[\]\']')
    return re.sub(regex, '', s).split(', ')
```

Note that all approaches so far use `split()`. This is a quite fast implementation which approach **C speed** and hardly any Python construct would beat it.

All these methods are quite **unsafe** as they do not take into account escaping properly, e.g. all of the above would fail for the following valid Python code:

```
['ciao', "pippo", 'foo, bar']
```

More robust alternative in this scenario would be:

1. `ast.literal_eval` which works for any valid Python code
2. `json.loads` which actually requires valid JSON strings so it is not really an option here.

The speed for these solutions is compared here:

[image: benchmark1]

As you can see, safety comes at the price of speed.

(these graphs are generated using [these scripts](https://github.com/norok2/BenchmarkTemplateIPY/blob/master/BenchmarkingTemplate.ipynb) with the following

```py
def gen_input(n):
    return str([str(x) for x in range(n)])


def equal_output(a, b):
    return a == b


input_sizes = (5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000)  
funcs = str_to_list_OP, str_to_list, str_to_list_regex, ast.literal_eval 


runtimes, input_sizes, labels, results = benchmark(
    funcs, gen_input=gen_input, equal_output=equal_output,
    input_sizes=input_sizes)
```

---

Now let's concentrate to the looping. What you do is an explicit looping, and we know that Python is typically not terribly fast with that.
However, looping in a comprehension can be faster because it can generate more optimized code.
Another approach would be to use a vectorized expression using Pandas primitives, either using `apply()` or with `.str.` chainings.

The following timings are obtained, indicating comprehensions to be the fastest for smaller inputs, although the vectorized solution (using `apply`) catches up and eventually surpasses the comprehension:

[image: benchmark2]

The following test functions were used:

```py
import pandas as pd


def str_to_list(s):
    return s[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(', ')


def func_OP(df):
    order_ls = df['product_name'].tolist()
    cln_order_ls = list()
    for i in order_ls:
        i = i.replace('[', '')
        i = i.replace(']', '')
        i = i.replace('\'', '')
        cln_order_ls.append(i)
    new_cln_order_ls = list()
    for i in cln_order_ls:
        new_cln_order_ls.append(i.split(', '))
    return new_cln_order_ls


def func_QuangHoang(df):
    return df['product_name'].str[1:-1].str.replace('\'','').str.split(', ').to_list()


def func_apply_df(df):
    return df['product_name'].apply(str_to_list).to_list()
    
    
def func_compr(df):
    return [str_to_list(s) for s in df['product_name']]
```

with the following test code:

```py
def gen_input(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        columns=('order_id', 'product_name'),
        data=[[i, "['ciao', 'pippo', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']"] for i in range(n)])


def equal_output(a, b):
    return a == b


input_sizes = (5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000)  
funcs = func_OP, func_QuangHoang, func_apply_df, func_compr 


runtimes, input_sizes, labels, results = benchmark(
    funcs, gen_input=gen_input, equal_output=equal_output,
    input_sizes=input_sizes)
```

again using the same [base scripts](https://github.com/norok2/BenchmarkTemplateIPY/blob/master/BenchmarkingTemplate.ipynb) as before.

Comment: I was thinking to go for list comprehension exactly. And also, when you do `apply(lambda x:)` it's essentially equivalent to the `for` and `append` loop, and then the added overhead for conversion to `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
(df['product_name']
   .str[1:-1]
   .str.replace('\'','')
   .str.split(', ')
)
```

Comment: Relatively short lists of rather long strings would spend more time in `str.replace`, which is much slower than `list.append`, both in data scanned and allocations made.

Comment: @QuangHoang with 2k rows, this approach seems to run at ~0.5x OP's speed, with 200k it is ~0.7x OP's speed (using the data from my answer). Above that I ran out of memory...

Comment: @norok2 you're totally correct. Strange, Here I thought that `.str` method has vectorization. Apparently it doesn't help.

Comment: @QuangHoang vectorization does help, but the `.str.` chaning seems to be just slower than plain old `apply()`, and `apply()` is competitive only for inputs above 500k rows. See the updates to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import ast
raw_df['product_name'] = raw_df['product_name'].apply(lambda x : ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about list comp as anky_91, so I gave it a try. I do list comp directly on ndarray to save time on calling `tolist`

```
n = raw_df['product_name'].values
[x[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(', ') for x in n]
```

Sample data:

```
In [1488]: raw_df.values
Out[1488]:
array([["['C1', 'None', 'None']"],
       ["['C1', 'C2', 'None']"],
       ["['C1', 'C1', 'None']"],
       ["['C1', 'C2', 'C3']"]], dtype=object)


In [1491]: %%timeit
      ...: n = raw_df['product_name'].values
      ...: [x[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(', ') for x in n]
      ...:
16.2 µs ± 614 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [1494]: %timeit my_func_2b(raw_df)
36.1 µs ± 489 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [1493]: %timeit my_func_2(raw_df)
39.1 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [1492]: %timeit raw_df['product_name'].str[1:-1].str.replace('\'','').str.sp
      ...: lit(', ').tolist()
765 µs ± 41.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So, listcomp with chain `replace` and `split` is fastest. Its speed is twice the next one. However, the save time is actually on using ndarray without calling `tolist`. If I add `tolist`, differences is not significant.